# Implementing VLC player in a Windows application: Programatically registering an ActiveX component

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry, activex

Im using the following guide to implement a VLC player inside my windows application:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/163016/How-to-embed-VLC-control-in-c-net-windows-applicat

(see the top rated answer)

On step 2 in the guide, it says that I have to register the ActiveX component:

```
regsvr32 "D:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll"
```

How do I do this programatically in the software so that the user doesn't have to? 
Im unsure on how to proceed here. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this routine to register your dlls

```
    public static void RegisterDll(string filePath)
    {
        string fileinfo = String.Format(@"/s ""{0}""", filePath);
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "regsvr32.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = fileinfo;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
    }
```